# Understanding why the Cantor function maps some Lebesgue measurable subset to a non measurable one

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, cantor-set

I'm going to present the following problem and a solution given in an older colloquium in Measure Theory in hope of understanding a statement in the final conclusion.

> $\boldsymbol{\underline{\text{Question:}}}$
>
> Suppose $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is a continuous function and let $\mathcal L$ denote the Lebesgue $\sigma$ - algebra on $\Bbb R.$ Prove or disapprove the following assertion: $$f(\mathcal L):=\left\{f(A)\mid A\in\mathcal L\right\}\subseteq\mathcal L.$$
>
> $\boldsymbol{\underline{\text{Answer.}}}$
> The statement doesn't hold. Indeed, define $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ by $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0,&\text{ if } x<0\\ c(x), &\text{ if }x\in [0,1]\\ 1,&\text{ if } x>1,\end{cases}$$
>
> where $c:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ is Cantor's function. Then, $f$ is continuous and $f(C)=[0,1]$ for Cantor's set $C.$ Let $B\subseteq (0,1)$ s. t. $B\notin\mathcal L.$ Let's consider the set $A:=C\cap f^{-1}(B).$ Since $A\subseteq C,$ and, from the lectures, we know that $\lambda(C)=0,$ and since $(\Bbb R,\mathcal L,\lambda)$ is complete, $A\in\mathcal L$. Since $f(C)=[0,1],$ we conclude that $f(A)=B$.

I have a problem understanding why $f(C)=[0,1]$ and $A=C\cap f^{-1}(B)$ implies $f(A)=B,$ since, in general $f(X\cap Y)\subseteq f(X)\cap f(Y),$ so $f(A)\subseteq f(B)$.
According to what I've looked up, the Cantor function doesn't seem to be injective, only continuous and surjective, as shown in threads [$(1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1580455/721644),[$(2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1267794/721644), [$(3)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3022143/721644).

I initially thought two seemingly different definitions (laid [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4262862/721644) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1906287/721644))  of the so-called Cantor function might be different and be the cause of my misunderstanding, but they turn out to be equivalent.

> My **question** is, is non - injectivity a problem in this particular argument?

---

Just in case, I'll mention I'm aware of a (continuous) Borel - measurable function $f:[0,1]\to[1,2]$ that we constructed in our lectures in a similar way as it is in Donald L. Cohn's  *Measure Theory*:

[image]

[image]

with the exception that we defined $f:[0,1]\to[1,2], f(x):=c(x)+x$ and took $A:=f^{-1}(S),$ where $S$ is a non - Lebesgue measurable subset of $f(C),$ where $C\subseteq [0,1]$ is the Cantor set and $A\notin\mathcal B(\Bbb R).$

"I have a problem understanding why $f(C)=[0,1]$ and $A=C\cap f^{-1}(B)$ implies $f(A)=B$": $B\subset f(C)\implies f(\{x\in C\mid f(x)\in B\})=B.$

Comment: If your text is too long for the title, edit the text, don't just end mid-word. The title doesn't need to give the question

Comment: "I have a problem understanding why $f(C)=[0,1]$ and $A=C\cap f^{-1}(B)$ implies $f(A)=B$": $B\subset f(C)\implies f(\{x\in C\mid f(x)\in B\})=B.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I haven't even noticed when typping, it wasn't on purpose. A thank you to everyone who improved the post.

Comment: The "problem" (or the advantage) of $f$
 is not its non-injectivity; it is that it maps some set of measure $0$
 onto an interval. Does *this comment* more or less answer you question, or does *the previous one*? (or none?)

Comment: @AnneBauval, maybe I wasn't precise. I think $f(A),$ where $A=C\cap f^{-1}(B)$ might just be a proper subset of $f(B).$ Let me just read your comment a couple of times, I'm probably just telling nonsense.

Comment: @AnneBauval, it does, the first comment, does. Thank you.

Comment: If so, I was wrong to criticize @Manifoldski 's answer (deleted at the moment), which probably requires less effort than my comment. I apologize to him. But the aim of your post was not clear (at least to me).

Comment: @AnneBauval, there was a banal lapse on my behalf. I forgot to use the fact that $B$ is also a subset of $f(C)$ and I thought the person came to conclusion just by mapping the intersection and claiming it to be equal to the intersection of the images, which generally doesn't hold.